Does a student who is learning in Israel for a year keep one or two days of chag?
If someone will be in Israel for all three Shalosh Regalim (Succos, Pesach, Shavuos) for one year, i.e. a yeshiva student, does he keep one day or two days of chag?
One the one hand he isn’t living in Israel because it’s only temporary and he doesn’t OWN his dorm, but on the other hand he would be staying for all the chagim in order without leaving Israel.
